# Type cast required for access to union member?

Tags: c++, casting, struct, unions

I have a question about the following code in C++:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    int age;
} Group1;


typedef struct {
    int id;
    char name;
    float time;  
} Group2;


typedef union {
    Group1 group1;
    Group2 group2;
} ServiceData;

typedef struct {
    ServiceData data;
} Time;
```

Then I have a variable:

```
Group1 * group1;
group1 = new Group1;

group1->id = 10;
group1->age = 20;
```

Then there are two methods defined like this:

```
void method1(ServiceData * data) {
    //inside the method call method hello
    hello(data);
};

void hello(Group1 *group1) {
    printf("%d",group1->id);
}
```

I call `method1` like this:

```
method1((ServiceData *)group1);
```

But inside `method1`, when the parameter `group1` is passed to method `hello()`, I want to get the value of id inside of `group1`. Do I need to do any cast in `hello` method? Or inside of `method1`, do I need to cast it to `(group*)` before I pass it to `hello()`?

Comment: You don't need to typedef your _struct_ and _union_ in c++. You may just use `struct Group1 {...};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a cast, just to access the correct field in the `union`:

```
void method1(ServiceData * data) {
    //inside the method call method hello
    hello(&data->group1);
};
```

Comment: I think that should be `hello(&data->group1);`

Comment: In this special case, the behavior is well defined.  If several different structures have a common prefix, you can access that common prefix with the type of any of them.

Comment: @JamesKanze do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore 9.5:1 *If a standard-layout union contains several standard-layout
structs that share a common initial sequence, [...] it is permitted to inspect the common initial sequence of any of
standard-layout struct members.*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
method1((ServiceData *)group1);
```

you should do something like this:

```
ServiceData data;
data.group1.id = 10;
data.group1.age = 20;
method1(data);
```

And the implementation of `method1` should look like

```
void method1(ServiceData * data) {
    hello(&data->group1);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you must write

```
  hello ( (Group1 * ) data);
```

(or write data->group1, other answer).

But do not do that, but use inheritance, if it's C++:

```
 struct GroupBase {
    int id;
    virtual ~GroupBase {
    }
 }

 struct Group1 : public GroupBase {
    int age;
    virtual ~Group1 { }
 }

 struct Group2 : public GroupBase {
    char name;
    float time;
    virtual ~Group2 { }
 }

 void method1 (GroupBase* data) {
    hello (std::dynamic_cast<Group1*> (data));
 }
```

Comment: You're advising him to cast a `union` to one of its member's types?

Comment: You're right, that's a stupid idea. But in my opinion, it should work.